# Wordpress showing page content and blog post content within template

Tags: wordpress

- WordPress v5.8.1
- PHP 8.0
- Apache

I have recently migrated a WordPress project from a server running PHP 5.6 to a new server running 8.0. In the process, the new server has an issue where a particular URL is displaying the content for a page as well as the content for a blog post.

The `wp_posts` table has records where a page and a post have the same `page_name` value. The post is a draft, the page is published and visible.

The page's template is a simple `page-job.php` file:

```
<div class="row">
  <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
    <article <?php post_class('main-content column large12') ?> id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>">
      <div class="entry-content">
        <?= the_content(); ?>
      </div>
    </article>
  <?php endwhile; ?>
</div>
```

I have traced is to `wp-includes/class-wp-query@get_posts:2028` where WP checks for a `name` in the `$q` array. When dumped out the `$q` array on the new server provides the page/post's `page_name` value in the `$q['name']` value, on the old server this is an empty string which means WP doesn't alter the query to search by `post_name` resulting in it picking up the blog post. Instead, it finds the page using `$this->queried_object_id`

```
if ( '' !== $q['name'] ) {
  $q['name'] = sanitize_title_for_query( $q['name'] );
  $where    .= " AND {$wpdb->posts}.post_name = '" . $q['name'] . "'";
} elseif ( '' !== $q['pagename'] ) {
  if ( isset( $this->queried_object_id ) ) {
    $reqpage = $this->queried_object_id;
} else {
```

What I'm having trouble with is why the new server is providing WP with `name` in this array? Where could this be coming from?

Answer (score 0):

Add `wp_reset_postdata();` in your while loop.

Comment: Default WordPress template files have no need to do this? I would have to add this to every template to ensure this problem doesnt happen elsewhere. Surely WP shouldn't be outputting drafted blog posts by default without needing wp_reset_postdata().